# Can we negate a statement this way?

Tags: logic

If there is a statement of the form:

$ \forall a$, $ \exists k$ s.t. $ P(x)$ is true

Can we negate it this way:

$ \forall a$, $ \nexists k$ s.t. $P(x)$ is true

Please, tell me if I'm wrong and if there are mutliple ways of negating such a statement.

Thank you.

Comment: Given a statement "every person has a parent", is its negation "every person doesn't have a parent"?

Comment: one person does not have a parent would be the negation.

Comment: @A.Asad Yes - but your version would be "for every person, there is no parent."

Answer (score 1):

Correct negation should be, $$\exists a , \text{such that} \; \nexists k \in \Bbb R , P(x) \; \text{is true}$$

Comment: How is this equivalent to what @AdrianKeister has said?

Comment: @A. It's the same. He says "for all values of $k$, $P(x)$ isn't true." What I am saying is "There exists no value of $k$, such that $P(x)$ is true."

Answer (score 1):

$\neg\left(\forall a \, \exists k | P(x)\right)=\exists a \neg(\exists k|P(x))=\exists a \, \forall k|\neg P(x).$